# attr not working in ie=edge, but works for ie=8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, attr, prop

i changed meta tag content from IE=8 to IE=edge. 
I had a multiselect.js plugin and its functionality broke(Select all/unselect all). 
while debugging, when i changed attr to prop, it started working. 
Is this the only solution or is there any other way, 
because I don't know where all this functionality broke because of ie=edge and it will be difficult to debug whole code.

Comment: What is it that you're setting, an attribute or a property? Ideally, you'll want to use whatever is best suited for your scenario. Post your code so we can provide recommendations...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: `function checkAllMtFilters() { $("input:checkbox[name=multiselect_gs_MultiUnit]").each(function () { $("input:checkbox[title='" + $(this).val().toUpperCase() + "']").attr("checked", true); }) }`   The above code works if meta tag is ie=8, because in the last line it has `.attr("checked", true);` but if change the meta tag to ie=edge, it won't work. Again, if i change the code to `.prop("checked", true);` it works.